# How do I force SQLAlchemy to convert attribute values when I construct a new instance of a model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have a model

```
class MyModel:
  my_int_val = Column(INTEGER(10, unsigned=True))
```

How do I force SQLAlchemy to convert `my_int_val` to an integer without having to load the object via query.

E.g. Instead of:

```
>>> model = MyModel(my_int_val='1')
>>> model.my_int_val
'1'
>>> type(model.my_int_val)
<class 'str'>
```

I would like:

```
>>> model = MyModel(my_int_val='1')
>>> ...explicitly convert properties to mapped types...
>>> model.my_int_val
1
>>> type(model.my_int_val)
<class 'int'>
```

**Update**

Here's the use case to provide more context.

1. Process a request that contains an object, determining if the object already exists in the database.
2. If the object already exists, run a diff process on the object in the request and the object from the DB.
3. Return a list of fields that were changed and their values, encapsulated in a RecordChange object with (date, field, value) fields.
4. Add the generic RecordChange object to the database.

Since I am first retrieving an existing object from the database, it's typed. In some cases, even though the values are the same, the diff process will find a difference e.g. "1200" vs "1200.0" because the values of the inbound object are semantically different.

The function I use to process the request (`get_field_changes`) is ignorant about the *type* of the object in the request which is why I'm trying to avoid explicit casting on the inbound object's field.

```
def get_field_changes(old: ModelMixin, new: ModelMixin) -> List[RecordChangeMixin]:
  old_data = old.__dict__
  new_data = new.__dict__

  key_filter = lambda key: \
    not key.startswith('_') and \
    not key in set(['id'])

  for key, value in old_data.items():
    if key_filter(key) and (value != new_data[key] or key not in new_data):
      yield {
        'field': key,
        'value': value,
        'created_by': new.last_modified_by,
        'created_date': new.last_modified_date
      }
```

Comment: `model = MyModel(my_int_val=int('1'))`. Why should SQLA be responsible for the coercion of types?

Comment: You can do this easily with a validator: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_attributes.html#changing-attribute-behavior

Comment: @roganjosh - I am dynamically creating models from dictionaries so I'm trying to avoid explicit casting. The values I am getting are guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: Well they're not, because your entire example revolves around strings being passed that you want to be ints, and `int(some_value)` is hardly difficult to type on a keyboard. Just convert the type as I showed; I don't get what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: @roganjosh I have provided more context in my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a Mixin class that puts a `"set"` event listener on each of the column properties of a class which will coerce the value to the object's python type when it is set:

```py
from sqlalchemy_app import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, event
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import FLOAT, INTEGER, VARCHAR


class CoerceMixin:

    @staticmethod
    def set_attrib_listener(target, value, old_value, initiator):
        return target.__table__.c[initiator.key].type.python_type(value)

    @classmethod
    def __declare_last__(cls):
        for column in cls.__table__.columns.values():
            event.listen(
                getattr(cls, column.key),
                "set",
                cls.set_attrib_listener,
                retval=True,
            )


class Model(Base, CoerceMixin):
    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    my_int_val = Column(INTEGER(10, unsigned=True))
    my_str_val = Column(VARCHAR(10))
    my_float_val = Column(FLOAT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inst = Model()
    inst.my_int_val = '1'
    assert isinstance(inst.my_int_val, int)
    inst.my_str_val = 1
    assert isinstance(inst.my_str_val, str)
    inst.my_float_val = '1.234'
    assert isinstance(inst.my_float_val, float)
```